# Firebase messaging, suscripcion a un topic en iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, firebase-messaging

tengo un problema en la aplicación para iOS que estoy desarrollando (mi primera aplicación en iOS) conectada a Firebase messaging en Swift/SwiftUI. Lo que quiero conseguir es poder enviar notificaciones PUSH a la aplicacion, y en parte esto lo he conseguido sin problemas, desde la plataforma Firebase puedo enviar notificaciones a los dispositivos iOS y las recibo bien. El gran problema que no logro solucionar es que soy incapaz de poder suscribirme a un tema y no se donde puede estar el fallo. Este es mi codigo con el que consigo que funcione las notificaciones pero no la suscripcion al topic:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging


class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        requestAuthorizationForPushNotifications(application: application)
        return true
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([[.banner, .sound]])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    private func requestAuthorizationForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { _, _ in }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
          Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
          Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "test") //Esto no funciona
    }
    
}

@main
struct mi_App: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

**Actualización**: El fallo es debido a que no entra en la siguiente función:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
          Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
          Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "test")
    }
```

He probado poniendo la linea `UIApplication.shared.delegate = self` encima de `FirebaseApp.configure()` y la suscripción a funcionado correctamente, pero a la vez la aplicación a dejado de funcionar ya que cuando se abre solo aparece una pantalla en negro.

**Actualización 2**: Ya esta solucionado el fallo, se trataba de una mala configuración en un indicador del Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer uso de los métodos para suscribir y des suscribir a un `Topic`, revisa:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging

El proceso de subscripción y obtención del token se realiza dentro de `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` como lo tienes en tu código, pero imprime si existe un error y si el valor de `deviceToken` en esta parte, ya que me parece que este puede ser el error por el cual no puedes suscribir al `topic`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
          Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
          print("Suscrito al topic!")
          Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "test"){ error in
                if error == nil{
                    print("Suscrito al topic!")
                }
                else{
                    print("Error: No se suscribiò")
                }
    }
```

Si tienes valor en `deviceToken` entonces lo que puede estar sucediendo es que en este caso deberías usar el método  `subscribeToTopic()` de esta forma:

```
.subscribeToTopic("/topics/test")
```

de esta forma puedes suscribirte a varios `Topics`.

revisa:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorgesys por la respuesta. En principio no imprime nada `Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "test")` (ni el if ni el else), para probar puse un print al principio de la funcion de aplication y tampoco la imprime, es raro porque parece que no entra. Tambien probe 'subscribeToTopic' en sustitucion de la anterior pero me da un error diciendo que no puedo usar la instacia de 'subscribeToTopic' con 'Messaging' (aparte que si no entra en la funcion no haria nada). Puede que todo esto sea algo simple que se me este escapando porque como dije, es la primera vez que uso xcode.

Comment: He probado a poner la linea `UIApplication.shared.delegate = self` justo encima de `FirebaseApp.configure()` y a funcionado! ya se a suscrito al tema pero ahora cuando abro la aplicacion sale en negro... a ver que falla ahora.